# adding custom preferences to android settings using phonegap/cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I followed below tutorial and I was able to add custom settings to my app using Android but I don't know how to integrate code given in this tutorial with cordova app.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html

I am new to android development and cordova development. Any help is appreciated.

I understood that cordova plugin concept can be used but not able to achieve my requirement

Comment: The tutorial you mentioned is not based on Cordova, it's for creating native apps by java.

Comment: Read the Creating Plugins section from the Apache Cordova website, anyway this is an advanced topic, you must first understand the correlation between Cordova and Java to begin with.